# IntelliJ AltGr suddenly changed usage (or alt)

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration, ide

This is a silly question and I apologize but I can not find the solution ANYwhere and I can't code with this situation but at the moment, when I press Alt + 7 or any number it opens some window in IntelliJ like the project structure or something like that, when before it always typed the curly brackets or square brackets. I don't know what caused this change as I didn't mess with any settings so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: i use windows 11

Comment: What's your default keyboard layout and system locale? Also, what's your IntelliJ IDEA version? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142642 may be related.

Comment: i use a default keyboard layout with QWERTZ (german) and system locale is English (US)

Comment: Do you use the latest IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 version? What was the version where it worked correctly last time?

Comment: it isn't version related im sure as i didnt update or get the new version in the last months and it suddenly stopped working today let me see which version i have though

Comment: i use 2021.3.3 but it has always worked

Comment: There were related fixes in the later IDE updates, please check if it works in the current release: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Um so apparently switching languages back and forth eventually fixes the problem